# printing a 2d object array with toString() method

Tags: java

I am trying to print out a 2d object array using the toString() method. i can display the array with a simple for loop but i want to use the toString() method. I'm new to programming so please bear with me.

Basically i declared my array:

```
          private Object [][]array;
```

and to print it out i used the for loop in the main method:

```
  `  for(Object []a: data.array) //instantiated my class to data in main method
     {
        for(object k:a)
       {   
           System.out.println(k)
         }
          System.out.println();
      `
```

But i want to use the toString() method and be able to called it directly in the main method using:

```
System.out.println(data);
```

How do i go about it? i am confused cause the toString() returns a string and i will have to override it. Do i have to cast? Please suggestions will help.

My output from the for loop is below and would like the toString() to have a similar output:

`Country   1983   1984   1985   1986   1987   1988   1989
 USA       0.1     0.2   0.4     0.5   0.6     0.8    0.1
 MEXICO    0       1.3   1.23    0.4   0.1     0.0    0.2
 Canada    1.3     2.1   0.3     0.1   0.0     1.1    1.1`

Comment: `System.out.println(k)` is the same as `System.out.println(k.toString())`.  You could also use [`Arrays.toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(java.lang.Object[])) to convert the array to a `String` representation, but you loose control over the formatting... *"i am confused"* - You're not the only one. What is wrong with your current approach?  What isn't working?  What is your aim?

Comment: @MadProgrammer yes i don't want to loose the formatting. It was a requirement to use toString(). Basically i am taking in 2 data types. One a string and the other a double. I have it working but need to override the toString() to display the same format as in the for loop

Comment: Okay, so what's the data in the array?  I think you're not providing enough information about  the problem at hand

Comment: @MadProgrammer the data in the array takes a string and a double array. I pass the String country representing each country's name and second, pass the array stats of each country. The country goes into the first row array[0][0] and its stored in that location. and the year is passed in array[0][i] and incremented. Next i check to see if each row is null. array[i][0] is null and if it pass the string country with it stats. But i want to display the information with the toString() method? Similar to the output i got using the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

what you're doing is the same as `k.toString()` (suggested by MadProgramme) if you wish to implement (better yet: override) your own toString then simply write a Class. See example [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/overriding-tostring-method-in-java/)

Comment: when i use toString() it provides me the address and not the actual values

Comment: that's because you're using Object. See this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()